# Change typeface size after \documentclass?

Tags: fontsize

I use the same tex file to create several different layouts with basically the same content. I have several switches and `\ifthenelse` constructs to control the layouts. Normally, I just have to set one or two boolean variables to activate a specific layout.

Some layouts require typeface size 10pt, some 11pt. Is it possible to change the size after `\documentclass{article}`? E.g., in a constuct such as:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{layoutA}}
  {\setlength{\typefacesize}{10pt}}
  {\setlength{\typefacesize}{11pt}}
```

Obviously, there is no `\typefacesize`. I would like to avoid having to change the typeface size in `\documentclass` all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, but I don't know exactly what the ramifications would be. Use at your own risk:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetfontsize[1]{%
  \let\small\@undefined
  \let\footnotesize\@undefined
  \let\scriptsize\@undefined
  \let\tiny\@undefined
  \let\large\@undefined
  \let\Large\@undefined
  \let\LARGE\@undefined
  \let\huge\@undefined
  \let\Huge\@undefined
  \makeatletter
  \input{size#1.clo}
  \makeatother
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{abc}
\lipsum[2]

\resetfontsize{12}
\lipsum[1]
\section{abc}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes allow to change font sizes mid-document. The command syntax is either `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{(new "normalsize" fontsize)}` or, should you need a non-standard baselineskip,  `\changefontsizes[(new "normalsize" baselineskip)]{(new "normalsize" fontsize)}`. The default value for the new baselineskip is 1.2 * fontsize. For details see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76170/how-can-i-change-the-fontsize-with-koma-script/223584#223584) by Johannes_B.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\blindtext

\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}

\section{bar}

\blindtext

\changefontsizes[18pt]{12pt}

\section{gnu}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn’t know this feature yet.

Comment: Should be noted, that the correct way to do this is `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}`. `changefontsizes` is for calculating relative sizes like `footnotesize` for non-standard base sizes. Meaning the calculated values overwrite the default/standard values.

Comment: Can you please change the part of the answer? I wrote some additional information at [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)