# How can I temporarily change the default font size commands?

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching to different font size(s) locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally)

I am stuck on a font problem. I use a specific document class for writing my dissertation: the font is `12pt` sized for the whole document, but on the first page I want to use the size of `11pt`.
The problem is that on this first page I use a lot of `\large`, `\Large`, `\huge` etc. and using this:

```
\begingroup \fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont ga bu zo meu \endgroup
```

does not update the `\large` etc.

So: does anyone know how to temporarily change the font size AND update the size used for `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` etc. ?

I know I can use KOMA scripts but it seems incompatible with one of my package.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \l@addto@macro already defined.
            Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I know also that I can generate my first page separately and merge the PDFs files, but I suppose it exists a simple way for doing that. No?

Comment: Perhaps the [`relsize` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) might be of help here?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question is really similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/change-typeface-size-after-documentclass, in your case you just need to change the font size twice. If this solves your problem, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If it doesn't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @Werner: I think the `relsize` package won't work for the OP because that package increments/decrements font sizes in 20% steps, whereas he/she is looking to reduce the size by roughly 10% only (from 12pt to 11pt). However, can one modify the resizing increment of the `relsize` package?

Comment: I once asked a related question: [Switching to different font size(s) locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a command that uses the definitions for the standard font size commands contained in `size11.clo` file and then use this command to change the sizes locally:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FontSizesXI{%
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9.5}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\FontSizesXI
{\tiny Some \scriptsize test \footnotesize text \small showing \normalsize the \large ten \Large available \LARGE font \huge size \Huge commands. }
\endgroup

{\tiny Some \scriptsize test \footnotesize text \small showing \normalsize the \large ten \Large available \LARGE font \huge size \Huge commands.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect! thanks so much! problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If using KOMA-Script is acceptable, work around the compatibility issue by declaring `\let\l@addto@macro\relax` after loading a KOMA-Script class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter

\let\l@addto@macro\relax

\newcommand{\l@addto@macro}{Hello!}% placeholder for package defining \l@addto@macro

\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\lipsum[1]

\changefontsizes{12pt}

\section{bar}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make the change? [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)