# BibLaTeX: Wrong indentation when changing font size?

Tags: biblatex, indentation, fontsize

BibLaTeX seems to calculate wrong indentation when I change the fontsize. The lines following the first one are a little to the left than the first line (see the red line).

[image: Picture that shows the problem]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,listof=totoc,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99,block=space,abbreviate=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{GLS:datasheet,
    title = "GLS Datasheet",
    organization = "Optoelectronics Research Centre",
    howpublished = "Website",
    date = "2004-09",
    urldate = "2013-07-01",
    url = "http://www.southampton.XXXX",
    address = "Southampton, United Kingdom"
}
@article{Labadie:First_fringes,
    author = {Labadie, L. and Mart\'{\i}n, G. and Anheier, N. C. and Arezki, B. and Qiao, H. A. and Bernacki, B. and Kern, P.},
    title = {First fringes with an integrated-optics beam combiner at 10},
    DOI= "10.1051/0004-6361/201116727",
    journal = {A\&A},
    year = 2011,
    volume = 531,
    pages = "A48"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**What can be done to avoid this?**

P.S.: Some texts in my theses have to be 10pt, and others (like the bibliography) 12pt. Sadly, this is given to me, and I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computing of the length `\labelalphawidth` is done with the default font size. In your case 11pt. You changed the font size before `\printbibliography` which has no effect of the computing of `\labelalphawidth`. The label width is calculated under `\bibfont`.

<sub>The following solution was provided by Audrey in a comment</sub>

To get the correct computing by `biblatex` you can manipulate the command `bibfont`. In `biblatex.def` this is defined as:

```
 \newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}.
```

So you could use

```
 \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\changefontsizes{12pt}}
```

in the preamble.

With your example:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,listof=totoc,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99,block=space,abbreviate=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\changefontsizes{12pt}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{GLS:datasheet,
    title = "GLS Datasheet",
    organization = "Optoelectronics Research Centre",
    howpublished = "Website",
    date = "2004-09",
    urldate = "2013-07-01",
    url = "http://www.southampton.XXXX",
    address = "Southampton, United Kingdom"
}
@article{Labadie:First_fringes,
    author = {Labadie, L. and Mart\'{\i}n, G. and Anheier, N. C. and Arezki, B. and Qiao, H. A. and Bernacki, B. and Kern, P.},
    title = {First fringes with an integrated-optics beam combiner at 10},
    DOI= "10.1051/0004-6361/201116727",
    journal = {A\&A},
    year = 2011,
    volume = 531,
    pages = "A48"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is no way to have this automatically done?... Just try something and look whether it looks better or not?

Comment: @DL6ER The label width is calculated under `\bibfont`. In `biblatex.def` this is defined as: `\newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}`. So you could use `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\changefontsizes{12pt}}` in the preamble.

Comment: Hi Mro, can you please edit according to [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)