# Koma Script and real 13pt

Tags: xetex, fontsize, koma-script

I read about these several questions, how to use a font size other than 10, 11 oder 12 (see e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)) using KomaScript, but somehow, that won't work for me. I use XeLaTeX to compile my document (in order to change the font also, but the problem already occurs without that).

Then using the MWE

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra} 

\begin{document}
    Dieser Text sollte in Schrift 13pt sein, ist aber 12pt
\end{document}
```

The warning then is

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <13> not available
>
> (Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 1366.

Which i suspect is due to `OT1` but how do I tell XeLaTeX to use `T1` (also because it's a german text, as the MWE might already suggest)?

Comment: I think this is only related to the *optical* size of the font, not the actual size. Since Computer Modern only has fonts for the 12pt optical size, not 13pt, it will fall back to the closest optical size available (but the text should still be 13pt).

Comment: So, he uses 12pt (optical) and scales that up to 13pt to get actual 13pt size but with a „12pt-look“ (of the vectorized font)?

Comment: Actually, my comment above is incorrect. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/how-to-remove-the-warnings-font-shape-ot1-cmss-m-n-in-size-4-not-available.

Comment: You might be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108732/5049 which explains what KOMA-Script's `fontsize` option actually does

Comment: That's nice to know and i am okay with the computed sizes, als long as it would really be `13pt` `\normalsize` and not still 12pt, because the 13pt are available with the font i use (or even XeLaTeX uses normally).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can ignore the message: It is only a side effect of the calculation. The font itself is in 13pt:

Add

```
 \fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont Dieser Text sollte in Schrift 13pt sein, ist aber 12pt
```

after your text to see the difference.

If you want to avoid the warning altogether add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to try - you're right. The warning is kind of misleading here, i think. The `fix-cm` worked for that MWE, but on first try not for my huge document - but i'll have to take a closer look on that.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this message you can write an own file `scrsize13pt.clo`.  As Markus Kohm said in his printed book (German version chapter 17.1, page 428; sorry, I have only the book in German) KOMA-Script with the option `fontsize=13` or `fontsize=13pt` searched for a file `scrsizexxpt.clo` or `scrsizexx.clo` with `xx` stands for the given size, here `13`.  If it finds this file a recalculation by KOMA-Script is not nececcary and you will get no warning.

You can use file `scrsize12pt.clo`, copy it to `scrsize13pt.clo` and change the values to 13 pt. Please be careful this it not so easy: You have to define for example for all fontsize macros like `\normalsize` or `\Large` the propper values.

Comment: I red about that (though not in the german book itself, though i'm german) - but as far as I saw, that's really not that easy, so for now Ulrikes answer does provide a better solution (though that might also be just for me) to my answer.