# Why do I get a warning about computer modern even though I'm using lmodern?

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I would like to use KOMA script with a fontsize of 13pt (see very much related question here: [Koma Script and real 13pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129535/42128)). Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes
(scrartcl)              for basic size `13pt' on input line 1564.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <13> not available
(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 1564.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <13> not available
(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 100.
```

While I absolutely understand the first warning (I'm okay with calculated font sizes) I don't see why LaTeX is complaining about missing font shapes in the computer modern font (I understand `cmr` stands for computer modern roman?).

I can get rid of the font shape warnings by using `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before the documentclass, but that seems strange to me (I want to use lmodern, not computer modern).

I guess that it is save to ignore the warnings (the PDF does not include cm), but I would still like to understand what's going on. I tried to defer the change in fontsize until after `lmodern` has been loaded, but it did not help.

[ Related question in german with an answer by Markus Kohm, suggesting to use `lmodern`: http://www.komascript.de/node/1137 ]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning is due to the fact that Computer Modern fonts are only available at “discrete” sizes. The problem is that, apparently, Koma classes process the `fontsize` option too early, when Computer Modern is still the default font.

You can remove the spurious warning by loading `fix-cm` before starting:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

You'll only get

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes
(scrartcl)              for basic size `13pt' on input line 1564.
```

that's unavoidable unless you use the `silence` package to remove it:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{scrartcl}{Using fallback}

\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

A different strategy would be

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\normalfont
\KOMAoption{fontsize=13pt}
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

but I don't recommend it.

Comment: The last part is very interesting. The `\normalfont` command is what I was missing... I was expecting the lmodern package to set the defaults somehow (but I guess that only happens at the beginning of the document). So why would you not recommend it? Because `\normalfont` should not be used in the header?

Comment: @shark.dp Yes, `\normalfont` is issued at `\begin{document}` and issuing it in the preamble is not the best thing to do, but it depends on several factors. The Koma classes should try doing the size computations at that place (after `\normalfont` is issued). Or just live with the warnings. `;-)`

Comment: If you set the font later using `KOMAoption`, additionally add `recalctypearea` as the fontsize is as well given to package `typearea`.

Comment: @shark.dp  Additional reading: [How can i change the fontsize with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 8):

If you modify your example to

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\stop
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

test
\end{document}
```

You see the warning about `cmr` comes before `lmodern` is loaded. So the class
sets up some fonts which are over-ridden later but still generate some warnings.

It's probably safe to do this (although I don't think I've tried this before:-)

You get no warnings from

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{lmr}
\renewcommand\encodingdefault{T1}
\selectfont
\DeclareErrorFont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}{10}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

test
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is why I tried to defer the change in fontsize by using `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{13pt}` until after I loaded `lmodern`, but it does not change anything. Is it KOMA that sets up computer modern or is it just LaTeX (by default)?

Comment: @shark.dp latex certainly sets OT1 encoding and cmr family as defaults, I don't know the details of koma internals, but I added a warning free version that might work....

Comment: Very interesting. I think this is similar to egreg's version below, using `\normalfont`. It just looks weird to set the defaults before loading the package.. but this could be changed with `\KOMAoption`.

Comment: @shark.dp If you set the font later using `KOMAoption`, additionally add `recalctypearea`.