# What is the default font size of a LaTeX document?

Tags: fontsize

What is the default font size of a LaTeX document?

Comment: It depends on the font-related options and the argument of the `\documentclass[<options>]{<class-name>}` command. Assuming you're use a basic document class (such as `article`) and don't provide font-related options, the default font size will be `10pt`.

Comment: No less important, perhaps, is the value for `\baselineskip`, which is equal to (about) 1.2 times the fontsize unless fiddled with.  Thus a simple `\the\baselineskip` will print the value for `\baselineskip` right in your document.  (Simple math to work backwards to the fontsize value.)  Also the standard classes will usually load, right after the `.cls` file, a `.clo` file (something like `size10.clo`), which is where many of these 'size' values are initially set.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc/24600#24600

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Short Answer**

10pt is the default font size unless you opt for other available sizes.

---

**Long Answer**

Depends on the document class you are using, but mostly it is 10pt.

- **article**: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **book**: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **report**: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **letter**: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **proc**: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **ext versions of the above** (extarticle,extreport, extbook, extletter, and extproc) *(the [extsizes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf))*: Again,  Default is 10 pt, other available options are 8pt, 9pt,  11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt.
- **[The ams class](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/tex)** (amsart, amsbook and amsproc), coming from the ams-LaTeX collection prepared by the American Mathematical Society: Default is 10 pt, other available options are 11 pt and 12 pt.
- **[memoir](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)**:   Default is 10 pt, other available options are 9pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt,60pt. Option `extrafontsizes` is available to indicate that you will be using scalable fonts that can exceed 25pt.
- **[beamer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)**: Default is 11 pt, other available options are 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt.
- **[koma-script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)** (scrartcl, scrbook, and scrreprt): Default is 11 pt. KOMA-Script does not use fixed fonts and attributes to emphasize different
  elements of the text. Instead there are variables that contain the commands
  used for changing fonts and other text attributes.

---

**Further Reading**

This one ([What are the available “documentclass” types and their uses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/782/14103)) will answer many supplementary questions you might have.

Comment: the ams document classes equivalent to article, book and proc are in the "latex required" collection distributed as part of tex live.  if you want to add a "group" item to this list, they default to 10 pt, with options 11pt and 12pt.  (ams classes differ from the base classes with respect to the top matter (input format and output presentation), and by the inclusion of amsthm, amsmath and amsfonts, but otherwise conform to the structure of the base classes to allow easy substitution.)

Comment: For a bit of background on KOMA-Scripts fontsize selection: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108569/

Comment: @barbarabeeton When you make a list, you always run the risk of omissions. Thanks a lot. Added.

Comment: Default is 10 pt for `article`  `report`  `book`  `letter` except `slides` From [LaTeX Reference manual: 4.1 Document class options](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#Document-class-options)

Comment: @MMA thank you for your nice explanation. From where did you get the information about the standard classes like article, book, report, letter?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood For these standard ones, I just knew and difficult to recall right now. On a more serious note, [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes) could be one of the places to find out. But there are plenty more.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood documentation on document classes is given in my [above comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155896/what-is-the-default-font-size-of-a-latex-document#comment356569_155899) and [texdoc latex2e](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.pdf) see `section 4.1 Document class options`.

Answer (score 17):

Based on a [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/15717) to [How can I test for the current font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14377/15717).  `\f@size` is the internal macro that holds the current font size.

Without specifying additional font size options to document class one can test the default font size. For example `slides` has default font size of ~20 pt

```
\documentclass{slides}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfontsize}{\f@size{} pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
The current font size is \showfontsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No idea why it shows `19.907 pt` not `20 pt` exactly unlike `10 pt` ?

Comment: It's been many, many years since I last used the `slides` document class. Is there any reason (other than inertia...) for still using `slides` if `beamer` is an option?

Comment: @Mico it's only my curiosity to find the default font size for a not widely used document class :). I do use beamer

Answer (score 16):

The `KOMA-Script` classes `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, and `scrreprt` -- unlike the standard classes and `memoir` -- feature a default font size of 11pt, which allows for typographically sound margins when using the paper sizes A4 or letter. With `KOMA-Script`, it is also possible to select any desired font size and specify it in any TeX unit of measure. See section 3.5 of the `KOMA-Script` manual for details.