# What is the defaults font in \documentclass{slides}?

Tags: fonts, presentations

Because `beamer` is more powerful, I am learning to use it to prepare my presentation. But, I prefer the default font style in `\documentclass{slides}`. So, I have two questions:

1. What is the defaults font in `\documentclass{slides}`?
2. How to use it in `beamer`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155915/14103).

Comment: @MMA: No, this answers a question about font *size*.

Comment: For your second question use the search in tex.sx: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=[beamer]+change+font+is%3Aquestion.

Comment: It is TeX's standard font: Computer Modern.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `lcmss` fonts (and `lcmtt` for typewriter type), but you have to make them arbitrarily scalable:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % don't load the usual fonts

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{lcmss}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{n}{<-> lcmss8}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{sl}{<-> lcmssi8}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{it}{<-> ssub*lcmss/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{bx}{n}{<-> lcmssb8}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{ui}{<-> ssub*cmr/m/ui}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmss}{bx}{ui}{<-> sub*cmr/m/ui}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{lcmtt}{\hyphenchar\font=-1 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmtt}{m}{n}{<-> cmtt8}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmtt}{m}{it}{<-> cmitt10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmtt}{m}{ui}{<-> ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lcmtt}{bx}{ui}{<-> ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}


\renewcommand\rmdefault{lcmss}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{lcmss}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}

Some text in a beamer \emph{slide} is \textbf{here}.

\begin{verbatim}
hu*{\lll
\end{verbatim}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also load the `lxfonts` that were created by Claudio Beccari, inspired by the `lcmss` fonts, with some differences.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % don't load the usual fonts
\usepackage{lxfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}

Some text in a beamer \emph{slide} is \textbf{here}.

\begin{verbatim}
hu*{\lll
\end{verbatim}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In there anything regarding TeX you don't know? =:-)