# How to Specify Intermediate Font Sizes in Memoir Class?

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I've looked at:
[KOMA - Set documentclass font to 9.5pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171195/koma-set-documentclass-font-to-9-5pt?rq=1)
and:
[How to Specify Intermediate Font Sizes in Koma-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200015/how-to-specify-intermediate-font-sizes-in-koma-script)
but keep getting the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
[fontsize=11.6pt].
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.6pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in,bindingoffset=0.5in{geometry}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{.5in}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Document class options are specific to the document class. If there is no `fontsize` key-value pair defined, then it won't recognise it. That's the case for [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). For specifying font sizes during the class loading, `memoir` only provides `9pt`, `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, `20pt`, `25pt`, `30pt`, `36pt`, `48pt` and `60pt`, not `11.6pt` (say). However, if you have scaleable fonts available they can be set at any size.

You *can* just set a font of arbitrary size using

```
\fontsize{<size>}{<bskip>}\selectfont
```

at the start of your document. In your case,

```
\begin{document}
\fontsize{11.6pt}{14pt}\selectfont
...
```

However, this will only temporarily set the font to `11.6pt`, changing with every font switch. Moreover, any call to `\normalsize` would change it back to the default document choice.

My suggestion would be to choose a default document font size that is *closest* to what you're after - `12pt` in your case - and then update `\normalsize` to select your `11.6pt` choice (together with its default `<bskip>` of `14.5pt`). Easiest here would be to patch `\normalsize` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). So,

```
\documentclass[...,12pt,...]{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\normalsize}{\@xiipt}{{11.6pt}}{}{}% Update \normalsize
\normalsize% Set \normalsize
```

---

`memoir` does support loading of arbitrary font sizes via its `*pt` document class option (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf); section **1.2.1 Extended font sizes**):

> If you use the `*pt` option then you have to supply a `clo` file containing all the size and space specifications for your chosen font size, and also tell `memoir` the name of the file. *Before* the `\documentclass` command define two macros, `\anyptfilebase` and `\anyptsize` like:
>
> ```
> \newcommand*{\anyptfilebase}{<chars>}
> \newcommand*{\anyptsize}{<num>}
> ```
>
> When it comes time to get the font size and spacing information `memoir` will try and input a file called `\anyptfilebase\anyptsize.clo` which you should have made available; the `\anyptsize{<num>}` must be an integer. Internally, the class specifies
>
> ```
> \providecommand*{\anyptfilebase}{mem}
> \providecommand*{\anyptsize}{10}
> ```
>
> which names the default as `mem10.clo`, which is for a `10pt` font. If, for example, you have an `18pt` font you want to use, then
>
> ```
> \newcommand*{\anyptfilebase}{myfont}
> \newcommand*{\anyptsize}{18}
> \documentclass[...*pt...]{memoir}
> ```
>
> will cause LaTeX to try and input the `myfont18.clo` file that you should have provided. Use one of the supplied `clo` files, such as `mem10.clo` or `mem60.clo` as an example of what must be specified in your `clo` file.

Comment: I am using XeLaTeX and .otf fonts. Is it still necessary to create .clo files in different font sizes? I thought .otf fonts scaled.

Comment: @user26732: Yes. The `.clo` file defines appropriate lengths defined for each of the possible font switches (`\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, ...). Using OTFs are good, but you still have to update the setting for the font sizes for each of the switches, for completeness.