# Change size of chapter/(sub)section headings to specific pt size

Tags: fonts, sectioning, memoir, fontsize

How do I change the size of my chapter headings to 35 pt, section headings to 24 pt and subsection headings to 14 pt?

I know I can change the sizes using `\HUGE`, `\Huge`, etc... but according to the memoir manual, `\HUGE` is only 20 pt when `\normalsize` is 9 pt.

```
\documentclass[9pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}

\chapterstyle{hangnum}

\newcommand{\vubfont}[1]{\usefont{T1}{qag}{m}{n}#1}
\newcommand{\vubfontbf}[1]{\usefont{T1}{qag}{b}{n}#1}

\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\vubfontbf\HUGE}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\vubfont\HUGE}
\setsecheadstyle{\vubfont\Huge}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\vubfontbf\LARGE}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Avant Garde -- 35pt}
\section{Avant Garde -- 24pt}
Roboto -- 9pt
\subsection{Avant Garde bold -- 14pt}
Roboto -- 9pt
\end{document}
```

(Also, is this the best way to change the fonts of the headings to Avant Garde?)

Comment: A quick solution would be \def\HUGE{\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont} etc... But it needs some more changes to be a real change of the HUGE command as it specifies some more parameters I think if no lines are breaking in your titles it will be ok. (You need anyfontsize package)

Comment: See also here for memoir : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323443/how-to-specify-intermediate-font-sizes-in-memoir-class... And check XeLaTeX (in compination with fontspec package if there are no conflictions with memoir) if you don't already know for whatever font you want

Comment: @koleygr one doesn't necessarily need `anyfontsize` for `\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont` to be working for any arbitrary sizes, but a scalable font.

Comment: @Skillmon +1... I just thought that my comment is general like this and did not checked if Avant Garde is one of them... but we don't really know OP's \normalsize (normaltext) font choice (so it may be usefull)

Comment: You (@titto) should also keep in mind, that TeX's pt differ from Word's (if you have to meet a specific layout, that is). The difference is very small (\epsilon_{rel}=0.375%), though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the end I defined 2 new sizes (\chapsize and \secsize) so as not to mess with the standard \Huge etc... I might still use those later on. Also it turns out \huge is 14pt, so I didn't need to change that for the subsections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new fontsize using

```
\def\<name>{\fontsize{<fontsize>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont}
```

Also, in memoir, when you use the class option 9pt, `\huge` is 14pt.

This works:

```
\documentclass[9pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}

\chapterstyle{hangnum}

\newcommand{\vubfont}[1]{\usefont{T1}{qag}{m}{n}#1}
\newcommand{\vubfontbf}[1]{\usefont{T1}{qag}{b}{n}#1}
\def\chapsize{\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont}
\def\secsize{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont}

\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\vubfontbf\chapsize}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\vubfont\chapsize}
\setsecheadstyle{\vubfont\secsize}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\vubfontbf\huge}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Avant Garde -- 35pt}
    \section{Avant Garde -- 24pt}
    Roboto -- 9pt
    \subsection{Avant Garde bold -- 14pt}
    Roboto -- 9pt
\end{document}
```