# Scrartcl 13.999 point 14.4 point but not 14 point?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, fontspec, koma-script, font-metrics

Can the `scrartcl` class make a true 14 point type?

It will produce 13.999pt, 13.9999pt and 13.99998pt, but 14pt produces 14.4 point type only.

Thanks :)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13.999pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}

   \makeatletter

\def\showfontsize{\f@size{} point}

    \makeatother

\begin{document}

  \showfontsize 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the `fontsize` to 14pt:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14.000pt]{scrartcl}
```

Produces:

[image]

Also changing the `fontsize` to 13.999999pt, 13.9999999pt, 13.99999999pt, and so on, also results in 14.4pt type.

Strangely enough this:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14.00001pt]{scrartcl}
```

Produces:

[image]

and this:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14.000001pt]{scrartcl}
```

Produces:

[image]

Closely related: [*How can i change the fontsize with KOMA-script?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76170/how-can-i-change-the-fontsize-with-koma-script/223584#223584)

Related: [*Scrbook: Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108569/scrbook-using-fallback-calculation-to-setup-font-sizes/108732#108732)

Comment: Even `13.999pt` produces a `14.4pt` font...

Comment: I'm compiling with LuaLatex and using Vollkorn, texlive 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04.  On my machine it changes over at 13.999999

Comment: I guess that 14.00002pt type is functionally 14 point.  It just seems curious that it seemingly cannot be set to 14.0pt.

Comment: That's because the font is only available at 14.4pt. You have to use a font that is fully scalable to all possible points.

Comment: So then why does it scale so close to 14 point, on both ends of the spectrum.

Comment: The resulting font size depends on whether the fallback calculation is used or a font size definition file for the size is available. For example, if you have installed package `extsizes`, `size14.clo` will be loaded. `size14.clo` uses 14.4pt for 14pt. You can make your own font size using package `scrfontsizes` or by renaming and editing an existing file like `scrsize10pt.clo`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

KOMA-Script supports several ways to set the font size. First of all, if you want `fontsize=`*<value>* it tries to load a font size definition file `\@fontsizefilebase`*<value>*.clo. If this is not found, it tries `\@fontsizefilebase`*<value>*`pt.clo`. If this is not found, it tries `size`*<adapted value>*`.clo`. *<adapted value>* is the font size in pt but with stripped `pt`, it results, e.g., in `10` for 10pt, `11` for `11pt`, and `14` for `14pt`. Last but not least KOMA-Script provides a fallback calculation for font sizes without font size definition files.

The default for `\@fontsizefilebase` is `scrsize`, but you can change it before `\documentclass`.

So with `fontsize=14pt`, `scrartcl` searches for `scrsize14pt.clo` and `size14.clo`. If you have installed package [`extsizes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes), it will find `size14.clo`. There you can find:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xivpt{17}%
```

and in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\@xivpt{14.4}
```

This is the reason for getting 14.4pt instead of 14pt.

If you really want 14pt, you need to make your own font size definition file. You can use `scrsize10pt.clo`, rename it and change the values. Or you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrfontsizes}
\generatefontfile{afsize}{14pt}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

to generate `afsize14pt.clo`. After generating the font definition file:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize}
\makeatother
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\def\showfontsize{\f@size{} point}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showfontsize 

\end{document}
```

Will result in:

[image: 14 point]

Last but not least

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=14pt}

\makeatletter
\def\showfontsize{\f@size{} point}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showfontsize 

\end{document}
```

Would also result in using 14pt, because `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=14pt}` uses the fall back calculation. This is the same font size calculation, that is used by `\generatefontsizes`. Nevertheless, in this example initialisation of some load time lengths of `scrartcl` could be done with, e.g., the font size of `size14.clo`. So combining both methods would be a save solution, if your document needs at least two LaTeX runs:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize}% setup prefix of font declaration files
\makeatother
\documentclass[letterpaper,fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
% Generate and use the font size declaration file, if is does not exist
\IfFileExists{\csname @fontsizefilebase\endcsname 14pt.clo}{}{%
  \usepackage{scrfontsizes}
  \generatefontfile{afsize}{14pt}
  \KOMAoptions{fontsize=14pt}
}

\begin{document}

\csname f@size\endcsname\ point 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SX!

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much.  In making the font definition file would I have to find the path to the other *.clo files and compile in that directory, and then texmf, or would compiling in a user directory suffice?

Comment: I meant rather texhash.

Comment: So `scrfontsizes` generated the file `afsize14pt.clo` which I then put in a folder I named `AltKomaSizes` in my `~/texmf` directory.  I then did a `texhash ~/texmf` which seemed to install the 14 point font system wide without having to use `\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize}` in subsequent documents.  Is what I did the right way to use the answer?

Comment: @AFeldman Putting the file `afsize14.clo` in a local texmf tree ensures that the file will be found *if* it is searched. But you have to use `\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize}` if the file `afsize14.clo` should be searched.

Comment: @esdd Thanks for that.  I found that what you have just said is true from later trial and error.  Is there a way of making the font be recognized as if it was native to the system, ie without the `\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize}` control sequence?

Comment: @AFeldman It is possible, but I do not recommend this. Maybe you share your document with another person or you use an other computer and you forget that there is this special file somewhere in your local texmf tree. Then it maybe difficult to find out why the document looks different.

Comment: With `\makeatletter \newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{afsize} \makeatother` before `\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}` and `\IfFileExists{afsize14pt.clo}{}{\usepackage{scrfontsizes}\generatefontfile{afsize}{14pt}}` afterwards you can ensure that the file `afsize14pt.clo` is generated in the working tree if it could not be find in the first run.

Comment: @esdd Thanks for the good explanation.  I will leave the command in my preamble to remind myself and others that I'm using my own .clo file.  I did notice that `\def\@fontsizefilebase{afsize}` works just as well.

Answer (score 16):

KOMA has two different systems to setup the font sizes:

A (small) number of fontsize options  (8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt 17pt, 20pt) load a `scrsizeXX.clo` (from KOMA) or (if found) `sizeXX.clo` (from the `extsize` package) where designated fontsizes are declared. You can add more options to this list by writing a suitable `sizeXX.clo` or `scrsizeXX.clo`. In this cases the actual fontsize can differ from the name (this is the same as with the standardclasses). This happens here:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}

Class scrartcl Info: File `size14.clo' used to setup font sizes on input line 2033.
```

It is possible that due to rounding error values near e.g. 14pt triggers the loading of a size14.clo too.

For other values of fontsize it will calculate the fontsize. In this case the fontsize will exactly as wanted.

For pdflatex documents is it still possible that fontsizes changes due to the declaration in the fd-files. E.g.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13.8pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

leads to

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <13.8> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 2033.
```

In this case you need e.g. the package fix-cm. With xelatex and lualatex this is not necessary.

Comment: Loading `scrsize….clo` or `size….clo` is not restricted by the font sizes, but by the available files.