# Margins are not set properly

Tags: geometry, scrbook

I need to process my book according to the following requirements:

page: a4size
font: 14pt
margins - all : 2cm
format: book, twoside, openright

I have used both extbook as well as scrbook, with and without geometry, but the left and right margins are not being set correctly. Help please...

```
\documentclass[a4size, 14pt, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{layouts}

\printinunitsof{cm}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[refpages]{gloss}
\usepackage[usenames]{pstcol}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 


\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=MidnightBlue,citecolor=MidnightBlue]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{breakurl}
\input{colordefin.txt}


\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1

\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
{\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
         \item[]%
}
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{dedicat}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}%
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}




\begin{document}

\pagevalues



\frontmatter
\author{astralsmith}
\title{The Best Test Book}

\maketitle

\begin{dedicat}
 \emph{To my family}
\end{dedicat}


\chapter*{Abstract}
\chaptermark{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Pro at sensibus qualisque, no verterem corrumpit duo. Vix choro eloquentiam an, nam ne diceret mentitum necessitatibus. Per id dolor inimicus honestatis, eos brute vitae ridens ea, ad has deleniti volutpat appellantur. Et quis convenire vel.

Cum homero perfecto ex, fabulas maluisset ei usu. Quo agam alienum an, eu vero aliquid est. Est probo tation in, ut consul facilisis consulatu his. Ea labores voluptatibus eam. Summo ceteros ei pri, sea cu novum quaerendum, eam zril petentium ex. No sit labitur argumentum consequuntur, ne quot delenit has, lorem petentium evertitur eu mel. Eu sea ipsum possim.

Ipsum saepe iuvaret ne duo, eos labores sapientem ex, pri an omnis oblique. Nec cu nulla graece referrentur, ad homero legere volumus has, mucius appareat aliquando cu eam. Eum ad labore apeirian, est labitur labores cu. Duo an elitr singulis inciderint, ius et idque utamur diceret. Cu aperiri fabellas persequeris duo, dolor nostrud vim no, per an ullum iracundia interpretaris.

Vel no suas everti voluptatibus, dicunt viderer signiferumque nec ea. Eum animal laoreet no, clita definiebas assueverit te has, id cum virtute petentium suscipiantur. Nostro impetus sed ex, postulant adipiscing et vix. Mel agam mundi reformidans eu, no etiam dolorum mel, mei ea movet dicant maiorum. Eu usu prima dictas animal, sit porro nostrum theophrastus eu. Clita suscipiantur nam ei, legimus neglegentur vituperatoribus ei eam.

Mea in ullum posidonium. Ei vim mentitum evertitur posidonium, mundi assentior theophrastus mea et, magna denique vis eu. Laudem dolorum fabellas duo ne, mea hinc imperdiet ut. Minim fabellas sea ei, ut qui animal epicurei. In sed postea instructior, nam reprimique scripserit repudiandae te.

Dolore docendi an has, malis fabulas torquatos et qui. Ad pri oratio menandri, scripta invenire his ne, vel cibo solum reprehendunt eu. Tantas repudiare cu sit, mea ea case impedit petentium, wisi solet delicata eum ad. Utamur adipisci laboramus per cu, ne brute soluta libris mei. His bonorum impedit corpora ad, an ferri mucius appetere eos. Viris epicurei pri te, natum affert quodsi mei ut. Eu eirmod verterem duo, vix ne ferri ludus vituperata, veniam mentitum invenire eam et.

Usu in tale posse, cum ut quas laboramus pertinacia. Ad eos summo utinam, id laoreet suscipit nec. Sit at sanctus omittam ullamcorper, sale harum ei pro. Cu quod nonumes quo, ei doctus facilisi eum, eu quo posse facete. Option nostrum officiis eos et, qui ut democritum neglegentur. At invidunt sensibus prodesset nam.

Fugit persius pericula an has, an dolore regione ius. Ne adhuc equidem ius, cu altera semper scaevola sed. Sonet voluptaria pri in, erant feugait splendide usu an, eos ut porro altera diceret. Ex vis sale meis, cum at facilisi philosophia. Agam lobortis vix id. In vidit accusata est. Ad eam delenit tibique forensibus, nibh necessitatibus ex vim, eam eirmod fabulas ei.

Nam rebum verear pericula ex. No eum sale malis inani, vel et modus error. Ei quo rebum verear dolorum, ad mel harum postea omnium. No eum doctus incorrupte, eius altera explicari quo ea, at labore dictas moderatius qui. Ad his adipisci gloriatur, id magna porro eos, qui ex case dicant. Ne ius solet epicuri, ei eos option quaeque quaerendum. Vis probo malis aeterno et, ex laudem patrioque cum, no duo mucius iriure definiebas.

Et consul voluptua sed. Eam ne tempor reprehendunt, est erant epicuri neglegentur eu. Epicuri suscipiantur eu ius, cu vero cibo ignota sit. Has ne nostro detracto signiferumque. Decore graeco nostrum ad vis, ne pro tritani eloquentiam.


\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Pro at sensibus qualisque, no verterem corrumpit duo. Vix choro eloquentiam an, nam ne diceret mentitum necessitatibus. Per id dolor inimicus honestatis, eos brute vitae ridens ea, ad has deleniti volutpat appellantur. Et quis convenire vel.

\section*{Overview of the best test}
Cum homero perfecto ex, fabulas maluisset ei usu. Quo agam alienum an, eu vero aliquid est. Est probo tation in, ut consul facilisis consulatu his. Ea labores voluptatibus eam. Summo ceteros ei pri, sea cu novum quaerendum, eam zril petentium ex. No sit labitur argumentum consequuntur, ne quot delenit has, lorem petentium evertitur eu mel. Eu sea ipsum possim.

Ipsum saepe iuvaret ne duo, eos labores sapientem ex, pri an omnis oblique. Nec cu nulla graece referrentur, ad homero legere volumus has, mucius appareat aliquando cu eam. Eum ad labore apeirian, est labitur labores cu. Duo an elitr singulis inciderint, ius et idque utamur diceret. Cu aperiri fabellas persequeris duo, dolor nostrud vim no, per an ullum iracundia interpretaris.

Vel no suas everti voluptatibus, dicunt viderer signiferumque nec ea. Eum animal laoreet no, clita definiebas assueverit te has, id cum virtute petentium suscipiantur. Nostro impetus sed ex, postulant adipiscing et vix. Mel agam mundi reformidans eu, no etiam dolorum mel, mei ea movet dicant maiorum. Eu usu prima dictas animal, sit porro nostrum theophrastus eu. Clita suscipiantur nam ei, legimus neglegentur vituperatoribus ei eam.

Mea in ullum posidonium. Ei vim mentitum evertitur posidonium, mundi assentior theophrastus mea et, magna denique vis eu. Laudem dolorum fabellas duo ne, mea hinc imperdiet ut. Minim fabellas sea ei, ut qui animal epicurei. In sed postea instructior, nam reprimique scripserit repudiandae te.

Dolore docendi an has, malis fabulas torquatos et qui. Ad pri oratio menandri, scripta invenire his ne, vel cibo solum reprehendunt eu. Tantas repudiare cu sit, mea ea case impedit petentium, wisi solet delicata eum ad. Utamur adipisci laboramus per cu, ne brute soluta libris mei. His bonorum impedit corpora ad, an ferri mucius appetere eos. Viris epicurei pri te, natum affert quodsi mei ut. Eu eirmod verterem duo, vix ne ferri ludus vituperata, veniam mentitum invenire eam et.





\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\chaptermark{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
I acknowledge everyone.
I am obliged to none.
\newline
\newline
Fantacyland, May 2020
\newline
astralsmith



\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX  SX! Could you post  an example of what you tried? Normally, with geometry it's easy.

Comment: The standard LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report`, and `book`) do not support `14pt` as the default font size. Are you willing and able to use an alternative document class, say `memoir` and/or `scrbook`?

Comment: This is part of my preamble:

\documentclass[a4size, 14pt, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{layouts}

\printinunitsof{cm}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

Comment: @Bernard the code is now posted, above. Sorry, new here - not sure how to post it in a proper way :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mico yes I am using scrbook. I also tried extbook, but not memoir.

Comment: @Mico thanks for correcting! Do you see the same problem?

Comment: @astralsmith - I don't experience a problem with the left- and right-hand margins. However, I notice that the only half of the page numbers is printed; the other half is cut off by the page margin.

Comment: @Mico I use pdflatex for compiling as I have PDF figures to insert -- compiling using latex gives problems. Yes, I also see the problem with the page numbers, I thought of solving it later...

BTW, I just checked the sample code with latex as well, the left and right margins are still not 2cm....

Comment: When I finally got this to run, I got the right margin value: 2cm = 56.9055pt.  You need to add 1in to \oddsidemargin and subtract a lot of stuff from\paperwidth to get the left and right margins.

Comment: Your code produces exactly the margins you want – checked with `showframe` and the ruler of my pdfviewer. The margins, in LaTeX sense  are *not* the intuitive margins, as explained by John Kormylo. The margins in `geometry` denote the intuitive margins.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I determined the margin values:

```
2cm = \the\dimexpr 2cm\relax\par
left margin = \the\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin\relax\par
right margin = \the\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth\relax\par
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `\layout` provided by package `layout` shows not only the values of the page sizes but also two pictures which explain the meaning of the sizes. Then you can calculate the values of the margins as shown by @John Kormylo.

```
\usepackage[
  margin=2cm,
  footskip=35pt% use a smaller foot skip to print the page number on the paper
]{geometry}
```

Odd pages:

[image]

Even pages:

[image]

```
\begin{raggedright}
  1in = \the\dimexpr 1in\relax\par
  2cm = \the\dimexpr 2cm\relax\par
  left margin = \the\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin\relax\par
  right margin = \the\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth\relax\par
  top margin = \the\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax\par
  bottom margin = \the\dimexpr \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight\relax\par
  foot skip = \the\footskip\relax\par
\end{raggedright}
```

[image]

---

**Additional remarks** regarding KOMA-Script options and commands.

`a4size` is not a KOMA-Script option.  But `paper=a4` (or `a4paper`) is default.

Use `fontsize=14pt` instead of only `14pt`. And if need this font size exactly read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306788.

There is no need to redefine `\cleardoublepage`. If the blank pages inserted by `\cleardoublepage` should use page style `plain`, you can set the class option `cleardoublepage=plain`.

If all chapter pages should use page style `empty`, redefine `\chapterpagestyle` to `empty` (default is `plain`).

You can replace package `tocbibind` by options `listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, index=totoc` and `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}`, if the TOC should be really listed in table of contents.

To indent paragraphs you can use the KOMA-Script environment `addmargin`. And there is a command `\dedication` which inserts a dedication page when `\maketitle` and option `titlepage=true` (default for `scrbook`) are used.

To get an unnumbered chapter or section with TOC entry and running head you can use `\addchap` and `\addsec` respectivly.

```
\documentclass[
  %paper=a4,% default
  fontsize=14pt,% 14pt is deprecated
  DIV=calc,% to avoid the warning regarding the missing default DIV value for 14pt
  %twoside,% default
  %openright,% default
  cleardoublepage=plain,% instead your redefinition of \cleardoublepage
  listof=totoc,% lists get an entry in TOC
  bibliography=totoc,
  index=totoc
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% table of contents gets an entry in TOC (not recommended)
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}% replaces the \thispagestyle{empty} on chapter pages

\usepackage{layout}% \layout shows the layout and the different lengths

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm,
  footskip=35pt% use a smaller foot skip to print the page number on the paper
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\author{astralsmith}
\title{The Best Test Book}
\dedication{To my family}
\setkomafont{dedication}{\itshape}
\maketitle

\layout% show the page layout of odd and even pages
\begin{raggedright}
  1in = \the\dimexpr 1in\relax\par
  2cm = \the\dimexpr 2cm\relax\par
  left margin = \the\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin\relax\par
  right margin = \the\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth\relax\par
  top margin = \the\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax\par
  bottom margin = \the\dimexpr \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight\relax\par
  foot skip = \the\footskip\relax\par
\end{raggedright}

\addchap{Abstract}
\Blindtext

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}% an indented paragraph
\blindtext
\end{addmargin}

\blindtext

\addchap{Preface}
\blindtext
\addsec*{Overview of the best test}
\Blindtext

\addchap{Acknowledgements}
\begin{raggedright}
  I acknowledge everyone.
  I am obliged to none.
  \par\bigskip
  Fantacyland, May 2020
  \par
  astralsmith
\end{raggedright}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```