From Markdown to PDF by pandoc: how to change the font-size to 13pt with using KOMA-script
I am using pandoc to convert markdown document to pdf. I know that if I use extrasizes package I can use the font size bigger than 12pt for article. But what if I want to use fontsize that is not supported by extrasizes packages (say 13pt)? I noted that using KOMA-Scrip packages may work, so I made YAML metadata block like this in my markdown document:
---
fontsize: 13pt
documentclass: scrartcl
...

This gives me pdf output that has fontsize 13pt. But it changes the font for title  chapter names, and their sizes as well. Is there any way I can keep them as normal pandoc article?

If you just want to change the size of the text, without changing the size of section titles etc., you could switch the size at the start of the document:
---
output: pdf_document
documentclass: scrartcl
---
\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont

ddd

(choose whatever documentclass you'd like, for extreme font size, you might have to combine this with a scalable font. Note that this approach won't change other font sizes like \small etc.)

Wow this works. Thanks so much! Could I ask one more question? I would like to make the fontsize for footnotes bigger (currently only font for the mainbody becomes bigger (13pt) so it looks a bit odd). Is there any way to do so? Thank again!

I would not do this, because it would not change the size uses by \normalsize and therefore all implicit or explicit usages of \normalsize would result in wrong settings. It would also not change related lengths. \normalsize is usually more than only setting up the current font size.

Unfortunately I do not really know, which font sizes you want to use for \Huge … \tiny and which other values for the other lengths set by the font size files. So this answer describes only how the document font sizes in KOMA-Script classes work and how you can change them.
KOMA-Script classes provide option fontsize so setup “uncommon” font sizes, which are all font sizes but 10pt, 11pt or 12pt. So you should be able to use:
---
documentclass: scrartcl
classoptions:
- fontsize=13pt

to select a document font size of 13pt and change all other fonts sizes (\Huge … \tiny) corresponding.
If there is a file scrsize13pt.clo this would be used to setup the fonts. If there isn't, but size13.clo (e.g. from extsizes) is available, this will be used. As a last resort, KOMA-Script can also calculate all sizes relative to 10pt.
So, because there isn't a default scrsize13pt.clo, you can write a new one and do, e.g.:
\input{scrsize11pt.clo}% or scrsize10pt.clo or scrsize12pt.clo to do basic setup
\let\@normalsize\@undefined
\DeclareRobustCommand\normalsize{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize{13}{15}%
  \abovedisplayskip 13\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \let\@listi\@listI
}
\let\footnotesize\@undefined
\DeclareRobustCommand\footnotesize{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt%
  \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
  \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 5\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \parsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep}%
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
% Maybe adapt here also \@listi, \@listI, \@listii … \@listvi, \@footnotesep and several other sizes (see one of the original scrsize<NN>pt.clo files)
\normalsize
\endinput

or copy one of the existing scrsize<NN>pt.clo to scrsize13pt.clo and change only the values you want;
or generate a new size file for 13pt using KOMA-Script package scrfontsizes.sty and than copy some size definitions from another one to the generated and rename the generated to scrsize13pt.clo.
BTW: Instead of using the prefix scrsize you can alternatively change the prefix used by KOMA-Script classes. To do so you have to redefined \@fontsizefilebase before \documentclass, e.g., use
\newcommand*{\@fontsizefilebase}{cabohah}

This is useful, if you want to change the sizes selected, by 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, because you don't need to compromise the original files, but can use your own set of files. However, I do not know, how to execute code before \documentclass when using pandoc (but this isn't a LaTeX issue but would be a pandoc issue).
See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306788/277964 for more information about the font size files of KOMA-Script and how to generate them.

Sorry, but currently I cannot test it. because I have no working pandoc installation and also no test file.
