# Size of letters not changing in pdflatex

Tags: fontsize

```
\documentclass[60pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}  % Horizontal line.

% Document body.
\begin{document}
Ляляляля!
\end{document}
```

I am a beginner, and am apparently missing something simple here. What I am trying to achieve is to increase the font size to 12 or maybe 14 points. However, the `12pt` option to `\documentclass` has no effect.

I am using `pdflatex` to generate a pdf file from the above source.

Comment: Possible duplicate/Related [How to specify font size less than 10pt or more than 12pt?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/15717)

Answer (score 11):

The `article` document class doesn't recognize -- and thus doesn't do anything with -- the option `60pt`. The only three font size options the `article` class recognizes are `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. Other document classes -- such as `memoir` and the KOMA-Script classes -- recognize many more font size options; however, to the best of my knowledge they don't recognize the option `60pt` either.

To change the font size within a LaTeX document, use the command sequence

```
\fontsize{<nominal font size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont
```

Applied to your example, assuming you want a baselineskip that's 20 percent than the nominal font size, one could generate the following sequence of progressively larger font size (using a geometric progression with a factor of 1.2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for better support of Cyrillic glyphs
\begin{document}
Ляляляля!

\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
Ляляляля!

\fontsize{14.4}{17.3}\selectfont
Ляляляля!

\fontsize{17.3}{20.7}\selectfont
Ляляляля!

\fontsize{20.7}{24.9}\selectfont
Ляляляля!

\fontsize{24.9}{29.9}\selectfont
Ляляляля!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use one of the `extsizes` classes and you will be able to use one of `8pt`, `9pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, and `20pt` in addition to `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` provided by the standard classes. These classes are extensions of the standard classes which just provide more font size options.

For example, using `extarticle` with `20pt`

```
\documentclass[20pt,a4paper,twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}  % Horizontal line.

% Document body.
\begin{document}
Ляляляля!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked well for me

Comment: @Vass Happy about that :)

Answer (score 4):

The Koma family of classes and memoir provide the facility of various font sizes.

```
\documentclass[version=last,fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case if you are tied to basic classes like article, you can make use of `scrextend` package, which provides some of the facilities as that of KOMA classes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{20pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584) Can you please make the needed changes?

Comment: @Johannes_B Feel free to modify. :-)