# Can I use lettrine to make only first letter capital letter

Tags: lettrine

How can I make a book where every sections first letter is bigger than others? I tried to make the following book format but the text looks like SUmmer rather than Summer:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{Summer 1972}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summer72}
\lettrine[loversize=-0.4, lines=1, nindent=0em, slope=0em]{S}ummer 1972 was hot.

\newpage

\section*{Summer 1973}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summer73}
\lettrine[loversize=-0.4, lines=1, nindent=0em, slope=0em]{S}ummer 1973 was hot.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's “angfang”?

Comment: @egreg: Anfang is … beginning.

Comment: @Bernard Actually, I think that would be Anfang, "an" being a preposition "on" or "at", while the verb "fangen" means "to grab."  The beginning is where you "grab on" to something, eh?  Of course, I fully expect a native speaker to correct my comment, but it's been a few decades.  I'm also guessing egreg knew all this.

Comment: I'm non-natine in English so I guessed the translation wrongly. Sorry.

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can configure the defaults for the lettrine in the preamble or in a configuration file so that you need not specify them anew at the start of each section.

I've minimised your example somewhat as much of it was irrelevant to the crux of your question:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
  \setcounter{DefaultLines}{1}
  \renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.4}
  \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\input MorrisIn.fd% only required for the typographical nightmare mentioned below

\begin{document}

\section*{Summer 1972}
\lettrine{S}{ummer} 1972 was hot.

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{% if you like typographical nightmares, you could even reconfigure midway through your document...
        \fontencoding{U}%
        \fontseries{xl}%
        \fontshape{n}%
        \fontfamily{MorrisIn}}

\section*{The Winter of Our Discontent}
\lettrine{N}{ow} is the Winter of our Discontent\\
Made glorious summer by this son of York\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: Lettrine with preamble config]

If you do not want the remainder of the first word in small-caps, you could do this:

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\upshape}% or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
\lettrine[loversize=-0.4, lines=1, nindent=0em, slope=0em]{S}ummer
```

by

```
\lettrine[loversize=-0.4, lines=1, nindent=0em, slope=0em]{S}{}ummer
```

Comment: Usually, the rest of the word should be in small caps. For this you should write `\lettrine[…]{S}{ummer}, with 2 pairs of brackets.

Comment: Well, yes but in my situation this gives me the right outfit.