# Is there way to make horizontal line on the top of the page that contains only a page number

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I tried to write a book of the following style: Is there a way to modify the upper horizontal line such that it does not have the word "Sisältö" or any other text except page numbers?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}

\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 

\linespread{1.3}
\vbadness=20000
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{Chapter one}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{beginning}
First lines.

\newpage

\section*{Chapter two}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{somewhere}
Some text.

\newpage

\section*{Chapter two}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{end}
The end.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove it from a select number of pages, or the entire document?

Comment: I would like to have that my book contains horizontal line on the top of the page and over that there is a page number but not any other text. So I would like to remove the text in every page of the document.

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the rule and the page number in the header, with nothing in the footer, do

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

That's all. Don't set anything else related to `fancyhdr`.