# How to write things on two columns?

Tags: formatting

I am going to try to explain my situation.

I have a document that has a small font and prints in code. Unfortunately it only uses one side of the document, leaving a big white space on the other. I am trying to fill the other side up to save space.

Here is a sample

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}

 \textwidth = 520pt \textheight = 700pt \voffset = -90pt \oddsidemargin
 = -10pt \usepackage{listings} \usepackage{color}

 \usepackage{lmodern}

 \usepackage{scrextend} \changefontsizes[8pt]{8pt}

 \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
 \definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
 \definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

 \lstset{frame=tb,   language=Java,   aboveskip=0mm,   belowskip=0mm,  
 showstringspaces=false,   columns=flexible,  
 basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   numbers=none,  
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},   keywordstyle=\color{blue},  
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   stringstyle=\color{mauve},  
 breaklines=true,   breakatwhitespace=true   tabsize=90 }

 \begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}

 public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {         
int min, temp;      
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {          
min = x;            
for (int y = x; y < numbers.length; y++) {

if (numbers[y] > numbers[min]) {
    min = y;}           
}           
temp = numbers[x];          
numbers[x] = numbers[min];          
numbers[min] = temp;        
}   }

 \end{lstlisting}
  \end{document}
```

If you compile, you will find that the entire RHS is white space. I want to fill that space with other text. Below is a quick screenshot of what is going on

[image]

Comment: I get a very short but quite fat document. There's lots of space beneath but none on the right. I've made your code into code but you need to remove the `>` marks so that people can read and use it easily.

Comment: What do you mean with "the entire RHS"? I don't understand your problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant that if you compile, you would see a insertionSort() method on the left, but I made the font small so everything on the right has white space.

Comment: See screenshot for details.

Comment: I've provided an answer below, but I am not sure of this is what you had in mind. Please let me know of your intent was different.

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

 \textwidth = 520pt \textheight = 700pt \voffset = -90pt \oddsidemargin
 = -10pt \usepackage{listings} \usepackage{color}

 \usepackage{lmodern}

 \usepackage{scrextend} 

 \changefontsizes[8pt]{8pt}

 \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
 \definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
 \definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

 \lstset{frame=tb,   language=Java,   aboveskip=0mm,   belowskip=0mm,  
 showstringspaces=false,   columns=flexible,  
 basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   numbers=none,  
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},   keywordstyle=\color{blue},  
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   stringstyle=\color{mauve},  
 breaklines=true,   breakatwhitespace=true   tabsize=90 }

 \begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\linewidth]

public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {         
int min, temp;      
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {          
min = x;            
for (int y = x; y < numbers.length; y++) {

if (numbers[y] > numbers[min]) {
    min = y;}           
}           
temp = numbers[x];          
numbers[x] = numbers[min];          
numbers[min] = temp;        
}   }

\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\linewidth]

public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {         
int min, temp;      
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {          
min = x;            
for (int y = x; y < numbers.length; y++) {

if (numbers[y] > numbers[min]) {
    min = y;}           
}           
temp = numbers[x];          
numbers[x] = numbers[min];          
numbers[min] = temp;        
}   }

\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical alignment can be controlled using the optional argument for `minipage`; in my example I used `t` for alignment at the top, but you could  use `b` for bottom alignment or `c` for centered vertical alignment instead.

Comment: I was trying to also write code beside it. It kind of did what I was expecting, except that longer code gets cut off.

Comment: @sidht so, you want to write two listings side-by-side?

Comment: yes, that is what I want, and possibly starting the code at the very top. Manipulating the page size doesn't seem to have a large effect after a certain value.

Comment: @sidht please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not another text that must appear in one column in the same page, a simpler alternative to the `minipages` is the `twocolumn` option in the document class (see MWE). You can jump to the second column and from here to the next page with `\newpage` or `\pagebreak`.

If you need some text in one column in different pages, simply insert `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` when needed. Both commands force a new page. You can use these  commands also in a document class without the `twocolumn` option.

If you need some text in one column at the top of the same page, use `\twocolumn[text in one column]`.

If you one column text before and after the lists of code, or more than two columns, then see the package [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

 \textwidth = 520pt \textheight = 700pt \voffset = -90pt \oddsidemargin
 = -10pt \usepackage{listings} \usepackage{color}

 \usepackage{lmodern}

 \usepackage{scrextend} \changefontsizes[8pt]{8pt}

 \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
 \definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
 \definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

 \lstset{frame=tb,   language=Java,   aboveskip=0mm,   belowskip=0mm,  
 showstringspaces=false,   columns=flexible,  
 basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   numbers=none,  
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},   keywordstyle=\color{blue},  
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   stringstyle=\color{mauve},  
 breaklines=true,   breakatwhitespace=true   tabsize=90 }

 \begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}

 public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {         
int min, temp;      
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {          
min = x;            
for (int y = x; y < numbers.length; y++) {

if (numbers[y] > numbers[min]) {
    min = y;}           
}           
temp = numbers[x];          
numbers[x] = numbers[min];          
numbers[min] = temp;        
}   }

 \end{lstlisting}

\pagebreak
 \begin{lstlisting}

 public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {         
int min, temp;      
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {          
min = x;            
for (int y = x; y < numbers.length; y++) {

if (numbers[y] > numbers[min]) {
    min = y;}           
}           
temp = numbers[x];          
numbers[x] = numbers[min];          
numbers[min] = temp;        
}   }

 \end{lstlisting}


 \end{document}
```