# Latex Listing Source shift right side?

Tags: listings, code, source

I am  using Latex listings package to add the source code in my document, but the problem is on the left side some character is missing as showing in the picture.

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

[image]

**Source Code**

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{6em}{3em}
\lstset{frame=shadowbox,captionpos=b,rulesepcolor=\color{black},identifierstyle=\color{black},caption= Java Class ,label=foo,numbers=left} \begin{lstlisting}
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

**Is there any command to shift the source code** ? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate ?

**MainFile**

```
\documentclass[letter,14pt,landscape,a4paper]{book} %{article}
\input{inc/page_style}
\input{foo}
\end{document}
```

**page_style**

```
%\documentclass[11pt,letter,landscape] {article}%{amsart}
%\usepackage{inc/weekly_calendar}
\usepackage{inc/monthly_calendar}%Comment week_calender
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{inc/xymtex}
\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage{inc/chemstr}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inc/example}
\changefontsizes{14pt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % either use this (simple) or
\usepackage{soul} % use this (many fancier options)
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage[inline]{inc/trackchanges}
\addeditor{Nivir} 

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{chngpage}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black}}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize{150pt},%basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    language=c,
    gobble=4,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip={2.5\baselineskip},
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]
    {0.133,0.545,0.133},stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    }
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,    % color of internal links (box color)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=blue,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue           % color of external links %cyan
}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
%\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0,1,1}
\usepackage[first=0,last=9]{lcg}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rand0.\arabic{rand}}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[inline]{inc/trackchanges}
\addeditor{N} %adding comments
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} %bookmarks
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}  %setting font
%\pagecolor{lightgray} %page background
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{11pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{bookColor}{cmyk}{90,0,0,1.90}%0.90\%black
\definecolor{oddcolumnscolor}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93} %long table
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains, calc}
%--------------------------------------------Fancy Heading
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
  \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
  \fontsize{70}{70}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
  \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-15pt}
{\Huge}
%--------------------------------------------
% display page numbers in the headings. Start with roman numerals %
\pagenumbering{arabic}%comment if you to start from index from the TOC
\setcounter{page}{1}%comment if you to start from index from the TOC

%--------------------------------------------Remove the empty pages between chapter
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

%--------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\StartingDayNumber=2 % Calendar start:1=Sunday, 2=Monday
\begin{center}
\vspace{-8mm}
\textsc{\large {\color{blue}\textbf{Schedule Roy \ArrowBoldDownRight }}}
\textsc{\large {\color{blue}\textbf{Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Administration}}}\\
\rule[10mm]{12.0cm}{1mm}
\vspace{-1.5mm} %ruller {}{long}{width}
%\line(3,0){250}
\end{center}
%\tableofcontents
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
```

foo.tex

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{6em}{3em}
\lstset{frame=shadowbox,captionpos=b,rulesepcolor=\color{black},identifierstyle=\color{black},caption= Java Class ,label=foo,numbers=left} \begin{lstlisting}
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: Could you provide an MWE?

Comment: @alexwlchan added the source code.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't give me the output seen in your image, can you turn it into a *complete* example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: As for this particular case, I think you might have a `gobble=4` set somewhere in your preamble, but without a complete example I can’t be sure.

Comment: So @alexwlchan is right, you've added `gobble=4` to the `\lstset` in the preamble. Also note that the M in  MWE means 'minimal', and the code you posted isn't really that. You can read more about creating minimal working examples (MWE) at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem comes in this line from `page_style`:

```
gobble=4,
```

which is eating four spaces from the start of every line in your code blocks.

Quoting from the [documentation for the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings):

> `gobble=⟨number⟩`
>
> gobbles ⟨number⟩ characters at the beginning of each *environment* code line. This key has no effect on `\lstinline` or `\lstinputlisting`.