# Error in compilation

Tags: compiling

I tried to compile the following document but got an error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{section}
demo
\end{document}
```

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.505 ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}

?
```

I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Load the package `wasysym` after the `ams`packages ( `amsthm` in your case)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a5paper, top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes{10.0pt}  % Change base font size

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{section}
demo
\end{document}
```

Comment: more likely `amssymb` for `\iint`.

Comment: sure, but it is easier to remember "after ams packages"

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{iint}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\restoresymbol{WAS}{iint}
```