# Command \iint already defined

Tags: errors

What does the error below mean and how I can fix it? I use *www.sharelatex.com*. My file *main.tex*  has 100 rows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}  %\toprule
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{wasysym} % symbols
\usepackage{amssymb} % symbols
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}


\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

%\clearpage
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
%\setcounter{page}{1} 
%\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}


{\large

%\input{alphb.txt}
%\input{pronouns.txt}
%\input{tobe.txt}
%\input{havegot.txt}
%\input{can.txt}
%\input{towas.txt}
%\input{could.txt}
%\input{had.txt}
%\input{wouldlike.txt}
%\input{casy.txt}
%\input{inqs.txt}
%\input{should.txt}
%\input{usedto.txt}
%\input{haveto.txt}
%\input{predl1.txt}

%\input{ukaz.txt}
%\input{clen.txt}
%\input{podm.txt}
%\input{ponep.txt}
%\input{mnozs.txt}
%\input{nep_1.txt}
%\input{privlast.txt}
%\input{pridm.txt}
%\input{wh_q.txt}
%\input{nz.txt}
%\input{zast_zam.txt}
%\input{deter.txt}
%\input{spoj.txt}
%\input{numbers.txt}
%\input{adverbs.txt}
%\input{theris.txt}
%\input{slovosled.txt}
%\input{rozkaz.txt}
%\input{week.txt}

}


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: the command for a double integral has already been defined then you load amsmath which tries to define it again. probably wasysym, do you need both packages? (and why are you loading  wasysym twice? you have commented amsmath out but it is included by mathtools.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need package `\usepackage{wasysym}` because I use some symbols. What does  _tries to define it again_ mean? I'm not a computer programmer. :-)

Comment: if you go `\newcommand\zzz{hello}` it defines `\zzz` but if you do it again it gives an error that `\zzz` is already defined. anyway just put `\let\iiint=\relax` before you load mathtools and that will undefine it so mathtools will define it again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It doesn't work.

Comment: I removed the packages `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{mathtools}` and it works. It's alright. Thank you @DavidCarlisle .

Comment: Yes it does:-) make lines 29 and 30 be `\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183363 --> Try this: Change the order of `\usepackage{wasysym} ` and `\usepackage{amssymb} ` (`wasysym` after `amssymb`). And by the way, you load at least `wasysym` and `graphicx` twice.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I tried to change  the order of  packages  but I didn't work. Never mind.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I removed the package *wasysym* and added the package *amsmath* as you said it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `wasysym` package also defines multiple integral symbols. You can load it with option `[nointegrals]` if you want to use the `amsmath` version, or `[integrals]` if you prefer the `wasysym` version.

I took the opportunity to clean your preamble: many packages were loaded several times. Also, you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools` since the latter does it for you.

As your main language has accented letters, you must add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to ensure proper hyphenation.

Final comments: it's better to load `xcolor`than `color`, as it can do more things, with option `[table]` if you intend to use colours in tables, and `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notable `cleveref`).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} %\toprule
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb} % symbols
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym} % symbols
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}    

\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
```