# Command \iint already defined, but i am not using the wasysym package

Tags: errors, incompatibility

I have the same problem as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356599/51537) question: I get the error \iint is already defined but I am not using the `wasysym` package. Here is my preamble

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is not related to the `wasysym` package directly. Instead, it is generated whenever the `amssymb` package is loaded after, rather than before, some other package, or packages, which also define macros such as `\iint`.

What's the solution? Simply load `amssymb` before, not after, `mathabx`.

In fact, it's usually a good idea to load *all* AMS packages before other packages that provide math-related facilities. E.g.,

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathabx,mathrsfs}
```

Note that the `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically. Hence, no need to load `amsfonts` explicitly.