# Compiling Error - amsmath, MultiIntegral -- Command \iint already defined

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, compiling

I get the following error:
[image]

I tried to do the solution in this answer, but get the same error. [Error in compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183363/error-in-compilation)

What to do?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[phd,tocprelim]{userdefined}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}
 \usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: searching this site for that error message shows several answers, this one for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356599/command-iint-already-defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `txfonts` package already defines the `\iint` macro (and a few others), so that when `amsmath` tries to load them, it cannot.

Solution: load `txfonts` after `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `amsthm`.

But `txfonts` is deprecated. You should use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` instead.

You also don't need `graphics` when you have `graphicx`. Actually, you shouldn't ever use `graphics`, it's deprecated. Same for `color`: use `xcolor`.

The `subfigure` package (which you were loading twice) is also deprecated, you should use `subcaption` instead (but I'll leave this one or your document will break *everywhere*. But consider updating).

Also, `hyperref` should be the last package loaded, with very few exceptions.

Finally, `fixltx2e` doesn't do anything these days. Just remove it.

From Bernard's comment: `epsfig` shouldn't be used any more (cf. `l2tabu`): `graphicx` does the same job.

(There are probably a few more I forgot to mention. If someone knows, feel free to edit/comment.)

It looks like you are using a very, *very* old template. You should probably update it.

Anyway, your preamble should look like this by now:

```
\documentclass[phd,tocprelim]{cornell}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}% Leaving this one, but you should change to subcaption
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=bottom}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: `epsfig` shouldn't be used any more (cf. `l2tabu`): `graphicx` does the same job.