# How to make TikzPoster work with font sizes larger than 25pt?

Tags: tikzposter

I am attempting to make the base font size that the entire document is based on to 36pt. TikzPoster only says they support sizes up to 25pt in the arguments for the document class. How would I change this base font size from 25pt to 36pt so the rest of the poster sizes scale automatically?

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[36pt, portrait]{tikzposter}
```

Comment: You can redefine `normalfont` using any arbitrary size, but have to redefine the relative font switches as well. `\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{24.88}{30}\selectfont}`<- this is actually the default for 25pt.

Comment: Essentially I would have to use the \normalsize command everywhere I want this size, and so on for the varying sizes. What I am more interested in is how to set the "normal size" and have TikzPoster automactically use it. I am talking something like this: \documentclass[36pt, portrait]{tikzposter}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use KOMA-script to help us.

As explained in [How can i change the fontsize with KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584/37907) we produce a new file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrfontsizes}
\generatefontfile{theguy}{36pt}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Running the above example will give us a file `theguy36pt.clo`. That file can be input into our document, but since it contains internal macros, we need to protect it using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\input{theguy36pt.clo}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\block{Walzing Wombat}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

There is quite a lot going on in the file, stuff that is not needed for a poster. You should of course take a look at this file and adjust it a bit. There is no real use for `floatsep`s within a poster, but the gap between text and an equation still matters.

Comment: As you can see, the calculated values are of the kind `xx.9998`, so a bit manual fixing is encouraged ;-). Please have a look at the KOMA-doc for more information.