# Using extsizes package changes the page margin

Tags: margins, fontsize, geometry, extsizes

My thesis documentation rules state that the page margins should be:

`left=4cm`,  and the remaining are `2.5cm`

I have done that using `geometry` package, but when adding the `extsizes` package to change the font size to `14pt` the margins are changed.

How can I add font 14pt without changing the margins.

Comment: try load `geometry` after `extsizes`

Comment: You can amend [How can i change the fontsize with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584) to your needs. Are you still using the same template as earlier?

Comment: Or just use `\geometry{margin=2in}` after loading `extsizes`.

Comment: @touhami and @Johannes_B. Thank you both ,  loading `extsizes` before `geometry` solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Package `extsizes` not only changes the fontsize, but also amends various skips as well as the margins. Changing the page geometry after loading the package will give fixed margins.

Comment: The OP posted that it helped him too. Please extend your answer to show some explanation.

Comment: If I don't have any, should I delete my answer? I added it just to make things more visible.

Comment: If you do not have any explanation then maybe delete your answer. Or you could transform it into community wiki (if you choose this version please remove the "It helped me" and add that you took it from the comments).

Comment: Honestly since the question had no actual answer, i think it's fine to convert the comment into an answer. In terms of the etiquette of doing so, the original comment has been credited and comments aren't answers so I think it's fine. If you could add any kind of explanation that might be nice, but I think this is fine