# Bookcover class and extsizes package clash because bookcover calls geometry

Tags: xetex, margins, geometry, extsizes, bookcover

To have my cover match the content, I need a `17pt` font size. Thus, I do this:

```
\documentclass[17pt,spinewidth=10mm,coverwidth=160mm,
coverheight=240mm,flapwidth=0mm,bleedwidth=3mm]{bookcover}
    \usepackage{extsizes}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{bookcover}
    Test
    \end{bookcover}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, the margins get messed up. This appears to be a [known problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275278/using-extsizes-package-changes-the-page-margin). However, I can't move `\usepackage{geometry)` to after  `\usepackage{extsizes}` as it is called by  `\documentclass{bookcover}`.

What should I do? I should notice that I have built `bookcover.cls` as described on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover).

Comment: Do you really need the full 17pt setup or do you only need one 17pt font?

Comment: I was going to ask same as @UlrikeFischer, do you need `extsizes` ? `\documentclass[spinewidth=10mm,coverwidth=160mm,coverheight=240mm,flapwidth=0mm,bleedwidth=3mm]{bookcover}
%\usepackage{extsizes}
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
\fontsize{17pt}{20pt}\selectfont Test
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}`

Comment: Hurm, that did not even cross my mind. I guess I can do without it.

Comment: Don't write any text outside `\bookcocercomponent`!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way in this case:

```
\documentclass[spinewidth=10mm,coverwidth=160mm,coverheight=240mm,flapwidth=0mm,bleedwidth=3mm]{bookcover}
\usepackage[fontsize=17pt]{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
    \bookcovercomponent{normal}{back}{Test}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this solves the problem?