# How to use EB Garamont Font with KOMA Script Font Size 16pt

Tags: fonts, fontsize, koma-script, scaling, incompatibility

I am using the `ebgaramond` package in my `scrbook` document. As a base font size I want to use 16pt but when I compile the document I get warnings like the following:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <16> not available (Font) size <17.28> substituted on input line 2251.
>
> [...]
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/eur/m/n' in size <13.3335> not available
>   (Font) size <14.4> substituted on input line 7.
>
> [...]
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/eur/m/n' in size <27.64795> not available
>   (Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 1.

(and so forth...)

I read another answer here, suggesting to use the `lmodern` package for freely scalable fonts, but (i figure) since this is specific to certain fonts, not including EB Garamond, this did not help.

So I have two questions:

1) Obviously: What should I do to resolve this?

2) Why does it happen in the first place? Shouldn't stuff like this be one of LaTeX's stengths? -- You just select a new base font size and, boom, everything is adjusted accordingly?

---

**EDIT:**
The solution suggested below (`\RequirePackage{fix-cm}`) is in principle correct. It turned out, there was yet one more issue with using both `SIunits` and `scrlayer-scrpage` at a time. Can you tell me why that is or how it could be resolved?

M(n)WE:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=16pt, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
% The following two do not like each other -- it works with either of them, but not with both o_O
\usepackage[amssymb]{SIunits}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hi}
\section{There}
\subsection{Folks}
This is an MWE.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [How can i change the fontsize with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584)

Comment: Probably `ebgaramond` is scalable in Cork encoding, so try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @Henri Menke Thanks, I already have that in my header -- so that's not the reason.

Comment: Can you please add a MWE?

Comment: None of those warnings concern EB Garamond.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get these warnings if you are using option `fontsize=16pt` before setting a scalable font.

To avoid the warnings you can load package `fix-cm` before the document class. Then the default font will be also scalable.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
Textt
\end{document}
```

Or you can first load the font and then set the `fontsize`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\normalfont
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=16pt}
\recalctypearea% recalculate the page layout with the changed font settings

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

But note that there could be packages using the font size that is set as class option (or its default value). So setting `fontsize=16pt` as class option would be the recommended way.

---

**Update** regarding the updated question

In package `siunits` you can find the lines

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{eur}{\skewchar\font127} \DeclareFontShape{OML}{eur}{m}{n}{<5> <6>
                <7> <8> <9> gen * eurm <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>eurm10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greek}{OML}{eur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{greek}{"16}
```

So it seems to me that there is a non scalable font used for `\upmu` producing the warning

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/eur/m/n' in size <16> not available
>   (Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 13.

Note that I get the same warning (only the line number differs) if I comment `scrlayer-scrpage` but use `\upmu`:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=16pt, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
 %The following two do not like each other -- it works with either of them, but not with both o_O
\usepackage[amssymb]{SIunits}
%\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hi}
\section{There}
\subsection{Folks}
This is an MWE. $\upmu$
\end{document}
```

And note that [`siunits`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunits) is su­per­seded by [`siu­nitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

Comment: If I make my document into a MWE (just `\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=16pt, twoside, fleqn, bibliography=totoc, headings=optiontohead]{scrbook}`, `\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, bottom=1.6cm, inner=3.2cm, outer=2.5cm, includehead, headsep=\baselineskip, includefoot]{geometry}`, `\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}` and some Headers and text) then this is indeed the solution. Without the `fix-cm` I do get these warnings, with it I don't. It still does not help for my real document though, so I will have to figure out which additional packages are the troublemakers. (any general ideas? ;))

Comment: found them... see my edited question above

Comment: See my updated answer.